# MySQL descending order not Shorting Correctly in Varchar

Tags: mysql

I have a table name test. In that I have to sort the Var-char Field. But When I tryed to sort, I got wrong output.

**My Table-**

[image]

**My Query -**

> select * from testtable order by test DESC;

**My Output -**

[image]

What I want,.

```
test
G450
G145
G56
G45
G4
G3
```

PLEASE HELP ME TO GET THIS OUTPUT.

Comment: @Daniel What is Collation, and where Can I find it sir?

Comment: Sagotharan you can find it in [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-general.html), but your specific problem is not related to collations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your format is always one letter followed by an integer, a simple way to do this is:

```
order by length(test) desc, test desc
```

That is, sort by the length first and then by the field.

Comment: it gives the result reversible. like G3, G4, .... G450. I want the First Record As Big Number